# jQuery/Javascript: How can I clear the recent searches on a textbox using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

When I click on the textbox, and type something, it remembers what I typed in previous searches.  I'm using chrome, so it might be caused by the browser itself.  I would like it so that when I type in anything in the textbox, it doesn't show me previous things that I typed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute to your form or input:

```
autocomplete = "off"
```